# How to run terraform apply --auto-approve in docker container using CMD

Tags: docker, dockerfile, terraform, devops, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to run Terraform within a Docker container in my Windows machine.
I am actually successfull in running Terraform within a Docker container. However I want to run the command 'terraform apply --auto-approve' instead of plain 'terraform apply' so that terraform dont ask for confirmation to apply the changes.

I am using AWS as the provider.
I have a dockerfile of my own which I wrote and it uses hashicorp/terraform:light as the base image.

The following is my dockerfile:

```
# Use an official HashiCorp Terraform runtime as a base image.
FROM hashicorp/terraform:light AS base
#To create working directory.
WORKDIR /trojanwall-infra
# To add contents to the working directory.
ADD . /trojanwall-infra 
# Copy the contents.
COPY . /trojanwall-infra
# To check the current version of Hashicorp Terraform. 



# Use the base image to create a packaged image. 
FROM base AS package
#To add to the working directory.
WORKDIR /root/.aws
# To copy the AWS credentials to root folder.
COPY ./Key/aws/config /root/.aws
COPY ./Key/aws/credentials /root/.aws



# Use the packaged image to create a final image.
FROM package AS final
#To add to the working directory.
WORKDIR /trojanwall-infra
# To Run Terraform init and initialize.
RUN terraform init
#RUN command inside the container.
CMD ["plan"]
CMD ["apply"]
```

The above dockerfile actually works, but it would ask 'yes'/'no' for confirmation while running as a Docker container.
I would like to use it somewhat as the following:

```
#RUN command inside the container.
CMD ["apply", "--auto-approve"]
```

But it says that this is an invalid format. Guess dockerfile's CMD cannot run multiple commands this way.

Can anyone provide some insight and help me out?

Comment: Can `apply` work without adding `terraform`, i.e. something like `CMD ["terraform", "apply", "-auto-approve"]`?

Comment: I dont think so. Actually if we are running Terraform normally, we can run `terraform apply -auto-approve` but don't think that's the case when running inside the container. When I ran the above as you suggested, I got the following error: **error from sender: failed to match excludepatterns: syntax error in pattern**

Comment: Without looking at the definition, I'm guessing the `hashicorp/terraform` runtime container has `terraform` set as its ENTRYPOINT, so you don't need to include it in the CMD.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with terraform auto-applying - the error is coming from somewhere else

Comment: Hey, I have fixed the issue. I ll leave the answer separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue using '**ENTRYPOINT**' in the docker file itself. The reason why simple '**apply**' and '**plan**' works in the Docker file is because **the command `terraform` is set as 'ENTRYPOINT' in the base image itself (ie, `hashicorp/terraform`).**

Having that in mind, I created a file named '**run**' (sipmply created a file with no extensions) in the filesystem and added the commands `terraform plan` and `terraform apply --auto-approve` into it and also added a new line of code `'ENTRYPOINT /trojanwall-infra/run'` into the **'.dockerignore'** file. Therefore, once the Docker container is created and run, if first fetch the **'run'** shell file in the file system and run it and making **`'--auto-approve'`** come into the picture.

Modified Dockerfile:

**.dockerignore** (Last section from the original one)

```
# Use the packaged image to create a final image.
FROM package AS final
#To add to the working directory.
WORKDIR /trojanwall-infra
# To Run Terraform init and initialize.
RUN terraform init
#RUN Terraform run command inside the container.
ENTRYPOINT /trojanwall-infra/run
```

**run** (File without an extension yet still acts like a shell file inside the container)

```
terraform plan
terraform apply --auto-approve
```

This was a new information for me and I hope this becomes useful for everyone who seeks answers.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Terraform are you using? My version (0.14.8) doesn't have an `--auto-apply` option, and I can't see it mentioned anywhere else on the web. I suspect you are meaning to use `-auto-approve`, which should work the way you've tried:

```
# ...

# RUN command inside the container.
CMD ["apply", "-auto-approve"]
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I meant 'terraform apply --auto-approve' (Have made corrections in the description. thanks). 

So, even running that, I am getting an error saying:

"error from sender: failed to match excludepatterns: syntax error in pattern"

I literally tried every combinations of commands. Still not working.

Comment: Tried:

`CMD ["apply", "-auto-approve"]`
`CMD ["apply", "--auto-approve"]`
`CMD ["apply --auto-approve"]`

Comment: These are the following errors that I am getting.  
**1. => ERROR [internal] load build context**   
         **2. error from sender: failed to match excludepatterns: syntax error in pattern.** 
Is there any way to auto approve the apply command?